# Apex Managed Sharing not working to share record with user who has no access

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing, recordtriggeredflow

I am getting this error when attempting to create an OpportunityShare record to a user who has No Access to the Opportunity. I have tried both with Apex (without sharing) and Record Triggered flow. My record trigger flows were working before but now it is failing with below error on every user in the system.

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id.

I have checked the following

1. Org Wide Sharing is private for opportunity
2. profiles have full CRUD permission
3. That users have not been shared the record in anyway
4. Not sharing with Community license of any type

I am pretty stuck on this. Like I said it was working before and nothing was changed I know of. I have ensured that I am not getting this error because the User already has access

Comment: What's changed?  If it was working, something has changed.  You need to work out what that is.

Comment: Check to see if there are related objects that cause the issue - this error is not always about the record itself, but sometimes relates to some key related object.

Comment: I can't identify what changed. The only related object that could be causing it are the opportunity and opportunityshare

Comment: My solution has been to create another object and have a trigger off that to share the record. That does work and has the same effect. Just is not ideal because creating an extra object